# ipad safari problem possibly due to scaling

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari

I made the following website:

```
www.appliedintelligentmarketing.com
```

It works fine in all browsers but I've recently viewed it in safari with an ipad and it doesn't work correctly at all when you click on a different page. I have tried putting the following meta tag in:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Doesn't seemed to have helped though. You will need to view it on an ipad to see what the error is, but basically the horizontal scrolling doesn't work properly. Anyone know what might be causing the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer to all of your problems, but I've experienced problems before when using scrollTo on an ipad-ready website, because mobile safari doesn't perform or receive scroll events the way a standard browser would.  You may want to test the animation by replacing your localscroll calls with a standard animate: `$('body').animate({scrollTop: posY, 2000});`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `width=device-width` parameter.  I found it was unnecessary and caused problems because the reported width changes depending on orientation.